# Display the amount of Paid items in my database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatable

I am using php and mysql to create a page that displays all of the jobs we have in the database. The data is shown is a table and when a row is clicked a modal window triggers with the information of the clicked job inside. At the top of the page I want a simple counter that shows amount of paid jobs, invoiced jobs etc etc. I am using the code below but having no luck...

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","databaseusername","password");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM jobslist");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This code as far as I am aware is counting the amount of INT columns set to 1 rather than 0. No matter what I try I can't seem to get it to count the amount of 'paid' items in the database or 'invoiced' etc etc.

Once the count function is complete currently I am echoing out the outcome as below:

```
<?php echo "" . $total;?>
```

I am sure I am overlooking something simple, but any help is appreciated.

EDIT: TABLE STRUCTURE INCLUDED

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcMJV.png

Comment: no, it's not I don't believe - more like counting all rows return from the query

Comment: Shows your table structure.  No way to help you without knowing how data is modeled.

Comment: `"select count(1)"` - Shouldn't you be counting something from the table, and not just a single hard-coded value?

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a column called `paid` you could restructure the query similar to the following. If you needed to sum the amounts involved that requires additional tweaking.

```
$result = mysql_query("select 
    ( select count(*) from `jobslist` where `paid`=1 ) as 'paid',
    ( select count(*) from `jobslist` where `paid`=0 ) as 'unpaid'
    from jobslist");

$rows   = mysql_num_rows( $result );

while( $rs=mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ){
    $paid=$rs->paid;
    $unpaid=$rs->unpaid;

    echo 'Total: '.$rows.'Paid: '. $paid.' Unpaid: '.$unpaid;
}
```

Comment: Why not one query with a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: there's always more than one way to skin a cat!

Answer (score 0):

When I do this I usually name the `COUNT` result. Try this out:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows FROM jobslist;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row['total_rows'];
```

If you do not want to name the `COUNT` result, then give the following a go:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobslist;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

Comment: This is by no way a correct answer.  Without aliasing the column,  mysql queries execute right.  His problem should be related to other issue.

Comment: He is fetching the result as an array. I believe that without directly naming that `COUNT(*)`, it will actually be stored in the row as `'COUNT(*)'`. I will update my answer to state this...

Comment: it should be `mysql_fetch_associate` then

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1) FROM jobslist
```

> *This code as far as I am aware is counting the amount of INT columns set to 1 rather than 0.*

No, this is just counting rows in your table and not filtering. If you want to count something with a specific filter you have to add that filter condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `MyCount`
FROM `joblist`
WHERE `MyColumn` = 1; -- assuming MyColumn contains the INT you're looking for
```

---

You should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you should change deprecated `mysql_...` to `mysqli_...` (look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) how to). But it's not the reason you fail.

Unlike you seem to suppose, `COUNT(1)` will not look for an INT column having value 1.
Instead you must use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(a_column_name)` (same result), *with adding a `WHERE` clause stating which condition is involved*.

Here you seem wanting to count records where a given column (say `the_column`) has value 1. So you should:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM jobslist
WHERE the_column = 1
```

Last point: you don't need `echo "" .` in `<?php echo "" . $total;?>`.
Merely write `<?php echo $total;?>`.